# Subgroup of an affine, algebraic irrducible group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $G\subseteq GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a irreducible, affine, algebraic group (Zariski-Closed). Moreover let $H \subseteq G$ be a finite normal group. I want to show that $H \subseteq Z(G):=\{g \in G|hg=gh \hspace{0.3cm} \forall h \in G\}$. I am not quite sure how to start. I think that if $H$ is not central, then it should be irreducible, but I am not sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G$ is irreducible, so for any $h\in H$ the set $G\cdot h=\{ghg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}$ is connected. But $H\unlhd G$, so $G\cdot h\subseteq H$. As a finite set $H$ is discrete, so this implies that $G\cdot h$ must be a singleton. Therefore $h\in Z(G)$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Why is the induced topology on H discrete? As far as i know the Zariski-Topology is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Zariski topology is not Hausdorff, but it is $T_1$. So all the finite sets are closed.